# Is there a way to make Google Cloud Pub/Sub Schema fields optional?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, avro, google-cloud-pubsub

The title says it all, really. I'm struggling to figure out how to make a Google Cloud Pub/Sub schema that has optional fields. Or would having optional fields in an AVRO schema basically directly contradict the whole point of having a schema?

The structure I tried is this, with no success:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "TestStringField",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "TestIntField",
      "type": ["null", "int"],
      "default": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the message you try to pass in using this schema and the error message that results when you call publish?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn
I am having the same issue and cannot find a solution to it. 

schema: { "type": "record", "name": "Person", "fields": [ { "name": "name", "type": [ "null", "string" ], "default": null } ] } 

message: {"name": "john"} 

error: Invalid JSON-encoded message against Avro schema. Incorrect token in the stream. Expected: Object start, found String

Answer (score 2):

There is currently an issue with supporting nullable fields with Avro schemas: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242757468.

Transforming the schema into a protobuf (proto2) schema worked for me. The messages themselves can stay in JSON format.

Your protobuf schema will probably look like this:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message ProtocolBuffer {
  optional string TestStringField = 1;
  optional int32 TestIntField = 2;
}
```

If you use GCP console, make sure to tick `ProtoBuf` for Schema type. Also note the ProtoBuf version 3 did not work for me. Stay with version 2.

Answer (score 0):

The schema as presented in the question needs to have the null values be the default since `null` is the first type in the union:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "TestStringField",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "TestIntField",
      "type": ["null", "int"],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

A message that wants to be have non-null fields would have to put them inside an object, e.g.:

```
{
  "TestStringField": {
    "string": "Hi"
  },
  "TestIntField": {
    "int": 7
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gcloud pubsub schemas create key-schema
--definition='{ "type": "record", "namespace": "my.ns", "name":
"KeyMsg", "fields": [ { "name": "key", "type": "string" } ] }'
--type=AVRO

Answer (score 0):

This is still an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242757468) at pub/sub with avro schema as Rudert stated. I moved to proto buffer schema definition with optional fields to mitigate the issue.

```
syntax = "proto3";

message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  int32 page_number = 2;
  optional int32 results_per_page = 3;
}
```

[documentation](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/)